# Finding and pasting string from multiple word docs fails part way through (pastespecial method of range class failed)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a VBA macro which opens up every word document for in a folder and finds a certain string in the document, and then pastes it into the open spreadsheet. All the word documents are of the same template and do contain the string in question.

It runs fine for the first 4 or 5 documents and then I get the error "pastespecial method of range class failed". The document it fails on is in no way different to the others and if I delete this document then it fails on another one. Can anyone help please? I'm new to VBA so my code may well be rubbish. 
Here is the full code:

```
Sub readForml()

Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim myWkSht As Worksheet

wdApp.Visible = False
'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

 myExtension = "*.docx*"

Set myWkSht = ActiveSheet
myPath = "path_to_folder"
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
'set i to be furst blank row
i = myWkSht.Cells(myWkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
     'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set myDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
      DoEvents


With myDoc.Content

        .Find.ClearFormatting
        With .Find
            .Text = "number[0-9]{4}"
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Execute
            End With
        .Copy
           myWkSht.Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


End With

      myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False

    i = i + 1
    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir()
    Loop

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance"

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with this code that *could* be causing problems. I'm not certain any (or the combination) are the cause, but let's see...

1. In VBA an object shouldn't be declared and instantiated on the same line. This is OK in VB.NET, but not VBA. So declare `wdApp` in one line, but `Set wdApp = New Word.Application` in a different one.
2. Use a specific `Range` object for the Find. Currently, the code is telling Word to copy the entire document, on the one hand, but the "found" is the search term - this is confusing for VBA.
3. Try putting `Set myDoc = Nothing` just before the `Loop` statement to explicitly release `myDoc` before assigning the next document to it.
4. It's usually a good idea to test whether the searched term was actually found. Not sure what you want to have happen if this should occur, but it's good to have the test.

Note also that a comment is inaccurate, the code is not looping the Excel files but the Word files. This isn't causing the problem, but it should be corrected to avoid confusion.

```
Sub readForml()

Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdRange as Word.Range
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim i As Integer, bFound as Boolean
Dim myWkSht As Worksheet

Set wdApp = New Word.Application
wdApp.Visible = False
'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

 myExtension = "*.docx*"

Set myWkSht = ActiveSheet
myPath = "path_to_folder"
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
'set i to be first blank row
i = myWkSht.Cells(myWkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
     'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set myDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
      DoEvents

      Set wdRange = myDoc.Content
      With wdRange   
        .Find.ClearFormatting
        With .Find
            .Text = "number[0-9]{4}"
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            bFound = .Execute
         End With
         If bFound Then
            .Copy
            myWkSht.Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
         Else
             MsgBox "Search term not found"
         End If
      End With

      myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
      Set myDoc = Nothing
      i = i + 1
      'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir()
    Loop

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. It still gets the same error but it runs better. It never says that the search term isn't found. When I comment out the paste special line and just make It bring up a message box saying that the string was found, it runs fine so every string is found. There must be something wrong with the pasting. Is it possible to do it without pasting? Can I set the outcome of the find to be some variable, and then set the relevant cell in my worksheet to be that variable?

Comment: P.S. I changed myWkSht.Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  to myWkSht.Range("A" & i) = wdRange and it works! Thanks a lot.